# Bug: lost reputation points after deleting a question and undeleting it!

Tags: bug, reputation, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

When we delete a question the reputation gained or lost because of the question is recovered. But, when we un-delete the question the reputation is not changed!

E.g.,

- You have 100 reputation points and you post an question.
- You get an upvote and your reputation becomes 105.
- Now you delete the question, so your reputation comes back to 100.
- Now, if you un-delete the question the reputation should be increased back to 105, but it remains same (100).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not all events affecting reputation are calculated and displayed in real time. Give it a chance to work itself out (usually less than an hour, 24 hours max). Your reputation should display correctly in short order.